# Xcode docset RSS feed for iOS 7

Tags: rss, documentation, ios7, xcode5

Is there an RSS feed for the Xcode iOS 7 docset? This is helpful for manually downloading .xar files for docsets. The RSS feed information was previously shown in Xcode 4 in Settings > Downloads, but is not shown in Xcode 5.

The feed address for iOS 6.1 is: http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone6.1.atom. For iOS 7, I've tried using http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone7.0.atom, but the link is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For modern Xcode there is no longer an official Atom/RSS docset feed, because Xcode uses a *XML* docset feed instead:

### https://developer.apple.com/library/downloads/docset-index.dvtdownloadableindex

With some XSLT, someone could turn it into RSS or Atom pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

here: ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS7.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Info.plist
You can find rss of new documentation.
So http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone7.0.atom is correct link but it works on XCode5 only :(

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and the only way I could get the complete `.docset` bundle (not the stub version with an empty `Documents` folder) was to have Xcode handle the download (Xcode Preferences, Downloads, then click the iOS 7 download button) and then grab the file from `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`.